# What evidence is there that Nietzsche was anti-consumerist?

Tags: nietzsche

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Anti-consumerists) indicates that Nietzsche was anti-consumerist.  What writings or evidence suggest that Nietzsche was anti-consumerist?

Comment: See [Consumerism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consumerism#Origins) : "The older term and concept of "conspicuous consumption" originated at the turn of the 20th century in the writings of sociologist and economist, Thorstein Veblen." Thus, from an historical point of view, it makes little sense to speak of "consumerism" regarding N.

Answer (score 2):

Michael Kilivris provides a survey of Nietzsche's approach to socialism and capitalism from a Marxist perspective emphasizing Nietzche's opposition to hedonism "and by extension consumerism". (page 34)

> Theoretically,  Nietzsche  considers  hedonism  a  close  relative  of  Christianity,  insofar as both seek to minimize pain and suffering. In *Beyond  Good  and  Evil*, Nietzsche  talks  of  a  “tranquillizing  (for  example,  Epicurean  or  Christian)  medicine...  the  happiness  of  resting,  of  not  being  disturbed,  of  satiety,  of  finally attained unity, of a ‘sabbath of sabbaths’.” [302] As such, hedonism violates Nietzsche’s  “formula  for  greatness,”  *amor fati*,  which  demands  the  affirmation  of  pleasure  *and*  pain,  joy  *and*  suffering.

That summarizes Nietzsche's theoretical objections to hedonism (consumerism). He took this theory seriously enough to put it into practice.

> Practically,  while  Nietzsche  paid  close  attention to his gustatory habits, he did so in the name of *strength*, not pleasure. Hence, his guiding concern was, “how do *you*, among all people, have to eat to attain your maximum of strength, of *virtu* in the Renaissance style, of moraline-free virtue.” [*Ecce Homo*, 693] We also learn in this discussion that Nietzsche “abstained” from alcohol:  “Alcohol  is  bad  for  me:  a  single  glass  of  wine  or  beer  in  one  day  is  quite sufficient to turn my life into a vale of misery... [I] cannot advise all more spiritual  natures  earnestly  enough  to  abstain  entirely  from  alcohol:  Water  is  sufficient.” [*Ecce Homo*, 694-695] There is perhaps no better proof than this that Nietzsche did not conceive of the Dionysian in hedonistic terms.

Kilivris may be an initial guide to reading Nietzsche with a focus on what might be called his anti-consumerism.

---

Kilivris, M. (2011). Beyond goods and services: Toward a Nietzschean critique of capitalism. Hunter College, 5(2), 26-40. Retrieved on September 5, 2019 at http://www.kritike.org/journal/issue_10/kilivris_december2011.pdf